# .htaccess rewrites for language redirection

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to handle different languages in my site. My htaccess should:

- redirect root to /browser-accept-language/ if is (en|fr|it), otherwise redirect to /en/ if browser language is unsupported
- redirect all /(en|fr|it)/path/page/?params to /path/page/?requestedlang=$1&params

Here is my code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^([a-z]{2,3})[-,;]?
RewriteRule ^$ /%1/ [L]
# if %{HTTP:Accept-Language} is not (en|fr|it) redirect to /en/

RewriteRule ^(en|fr|it)/(.*)$  $2?requestedlang=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
#...other rules...#
```

But is incomplete and it doesn't work. How can i fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^([a-z]{2,3})
RewriteRule ^$ /%1/ [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(en|it|fr)/
RewriteRule ^[a-z]{2,3}/$ /en/ [L]

RewriteRule ^(en|fr|it)/(.+)$ $2?requestedlang=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Doesn't work:   `Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request`.